# Conditional probability greater than 1. Why?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, geometric-series

Let's say I roll a fair die independently many times. Let $X_i$ be the outcome of the $i$th roll. Assume that on the $k$th roll, I get a $1$ or $X_k = 1$ (**Edit based on comments**: assume this is the first $1$). What is the probability that I never rolled an even number before rolling this $1$?

I can solve this in two ways and get a gibberish answer if I condition. Let me demonstrate.

#### Gibberish with conditioning

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{\overbrace{X_1 \notin \{2,4,6\}, \dots , X_{k-1} \notin \{2,4,6\}}^{A_{k-1}} \mid X_k = 1 \}
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}\{X_k = 1 \mid A_{k-1}\} \mathbb{P}\{A_{k-1}\}}{\mathbb{P}\{X_k = 1\}}
\\\\
&\stackrel{\text{ind}}{=} \frac{\mathbb{P}\{X_k = 1\} \mathbb{P}\{A_{k-1}\}}{\mathbb{P}\{X_k = 1\}}
\\\\
&= \mathbb{P}\{A_{k-1}\}
\\\\
&\stackrel{\text{ind}}{=} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \mathbb{P}\{X_i \notin \{2,4,6\}\}
\\\\
&= \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{k-1}
\end{align}
$$

Now we just need to handle every possible $k$, so

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Big( \frac{1}{2} \Big)^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Big( \frac{1}{2} \Big)^{k} \stackrel{\text{geometric series}}{=} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 2
$$

which is obviously gibberish.

#### Without conditioning

Note that if I don't condition, I'm okay:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{\overbrace{X_1 \notin \{2,4,6\}, \dots , X_{k-1} \notin \{2,4,6\}}^{A_{k-1}}, X_k = 1 \}
&= \mathbb{P}\{X_k = 1 \mid A_{k-1}\} \mathbb{P}\{A_{k-1}\}
\\\\
&\stackrel{\text{ind}}{=} \mathbb{P}\{X_k = 1\} \mathbb{P}\{A_{k-1}\}
\\\\
&\stackrel{\text{ind}}{=} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \mathbb{P}\{X_k = 1\} \mathbb{P}\{X_i \notin \{2,4,6\}\}
\\\\
&= \Big( \frac{1}{6} \Big) \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{k-1}
\end{align}
$$

and therefore

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Big( \frac{1}{6} \Big) \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{k-1} = \frac{1}{6} \cdot 2 = \frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. It appears that you keep rolling until you roll a 1, and then you stop. In that case, B.Goddard's answer would be correct. For instance, if you look at the first two terms, you have the probability that you roll a 1 on the first roll plus the probability that you do not roll an even number on the first roll times the probability that you roll a 1 on the second roll. These probabilities overlap (you are counting the possibility that you roll a 1 on the first roll and again on the second roll). However, you already counted that possibility.

Comment: The events $\{A_{k-1}\cap \{X_k=1\}\}$ and $\{A_{k}\cap \{X_{k+1}=1\}\}$ are not disjoint. So what does the (infinite) sum represent here?

Comment: Thank you, @d.k.o., that is much more concise than what I was trying to explain.

Comment: Yes, @d.k.o.'s explanation makes sense.

Comment: @gwg Suppose that $\{\{A_{k-1}\cap B_k\},k\ge 1\}$ are disjoint and their union is $C$. Then
$$
\mathsf{P}(C)=\sum_{k\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(A_{k-1}\cap B_k)=\sum_{k\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(A_{k-1}\mid B_k)\mathsf{P}(B_k).
$$

Comment: @d.k.o., I think your comment explained it best. I put it as an answer for my own understanding, but if you write it up, I'll accept it and delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

The since the first few rolls can't be even and can't be 1, the probability of each conditional is $1/3$, not $1/2.$

Comment: It does not say that the roll cannot be a 1 before the final roll. It says that the roll cannot be even before *this* one. Which seems to imply that it can be a 1 every roll, so long as the $k$-th roll is also a 1.

Comment: Can you make this precise? What do you mean by "first few" rolls? Also, the first few rolls can be a $1$. I'm also not sure what the "probability of each conditional" refers to. It would help if you used notation.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe  He can't be talking about a particular fixed $k$, since he ends by accounting for "every possible $k$."  THAT implies that he's looking for the first time a $1$ appears.

Comment: Ah, I see now why my first solution implies rolling until the first 1.

Answer (score 1):

Synthesizing from the comments, my answer in notation is as follows. If two events $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B)$. But in my problem, $A_{k-1}$ and $A_k$ are *not* disjoint events:

$$
\begin{align}
A_{k-1} &= \{X_1 \notin \{1,2,3\}, \dots, X_{k-1} \notin \{1,2,3\}\}
\\
A_{k} &= \{X_1 \notin \{1,2,3\}, \dots, X_{k-1} \notin \{1,2,3\}, X_k \notin \{1,2,3\}\}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, my infinite series

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\{A_{k-1}\}
$$

does not adhere to basic rules of probability.